# OAuth error in Evernote SDK sample for android.

Tags: android, oauth, evernote

I am getting an error in the process of OAuth in evernote SDK sample HelloEDAM.

org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this

Is there any way to get rid off this problem?

Comment: Probably best to ask this question on the Evernote developer forum: http://discussion.evernote.com/forum/61-evernote-for-developers/

Answer (score 1):

The exception should include the actual response body:

```
throw new OAuthException("Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: '" + response + "'", null);
```

Can you add that so we can see what you're getting back?

Comment: <hash>                                       <request>/oauth/access_token</request>                     <error>Invalid / expired Token</error>                          </hash>  This is the response I am getting.What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late... but I'll answer for *future visitants*.
Probably you didn't change the `EVERNOTE_CONSUMER_KEY` and the `EVERNOTE_CONSUMER_SECRET` by default.

You must to ask for an API key at the Evernote for Developers webpage:
https://dev.evernote.com/

You should add that in your `gradle.properties`, and follow the instructions at
https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-android

Disclaimer: At least, I'm getting the same exception today with the latest Evernote SDK, I don't know how it was three years ago.